# Why is my upload speed is much less than my download speed?

Tags: internet-connection, utorrent

My download speed can go up to 1 or 2 Mbps but my upload speed barely goes above 100 kbps. I have tried checking on my preferences on my utorrent and also firewall and they all seem to be at optimal levels for uploading. Please help. Thank you!

Answer (score 12):

You probably have ADSL.  The A is for Asymmetric, meaning uploads and downloads are different speeds.  You have only so much bandwidth in your pipe, and the thinking is, as a home user not running servers, you're much much more likely to be downloading than uploading, so you bias the split towards the download.

This is using somewhat dated ideas of client and server in pre cloud/P2P days, but it's still more or less true that you download more than upload.

Comment: And it's also a price/market segmentation: If you need the same bandwidth in both directions it's available, but vastly more expensive - it's primarily sold to businesses.

Comment: It also sounds to me they are able to charge much more to businesses requiring servers.

Comment: Can this be because upload also takes more resources for ISPs and causes more traffic?

Answer (score 4):

It is most likely because that is what your ISP has limited you to.  Most end users download much more than they upload, so ISPs give us more DL bandwidth than UL bandwidth.

Go run a [speed test](http://www.speakeasy.net/speedtest/) to see what your actual bandwidth is.  Make sure you have all your downloads and stuff TURNED OFF before you do the speed test or your results will be skewed.

Answer (score 4):

usually because the provider gives you a much higer speed for download than for upload.
If you are a home user, or even a normal company, most of the time you download way more than you upload.
Only servers that serve services need more upload that download.

Answer (score 1):

I do not think this is due to the type of connection.
If the data can flow faster when downloading, I do not see why it couldn't do the same when uploading. I think it is mostly due to restrictions set by your ISP.

I personally have a VDSL connection, when running a test on speedtest.net, I get 18Mbps/sec download and 1.87 Mb/sec upload.

Note that having a slower upload connection will limit you using a NAS for example. I've tried a Synology one, the device itself is great, but trying to access it from outside (eg from work) is a pain because the connection is so slow